# Tesseract - Error : Params model::Incomplete line error

Tags: runtime-error, ocr, tesseract

Im facing some difficulties while using Tesseract.
First let me present my actual configuration.
Im working on Windows and have this Tesseract version :

tesseract 3.05.00dev
 leptonica-1.73
  libgif 4.1.6(?) : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.4.2) : lib
.0.6 : zlib 1.2.8 : libwebp 0.4.3 : libopenjp2 2.1.0

I have added every languages available with the msi installation.
Unfortunately, i am not able to run a conversion with dutch, italian, spanish, and french languages.

Im using the cmd to execute tesseract.
To show you what kind of error i keep having, im going to use a pretty simple example.

When I run that :

***tesseract MainMenu.tif result -l deu***

I keep having this error endlessly :

***Params model::Incomplete line***

That is pretty weird and i am unable to spot whats going wrong.
I can convert in any other languages without any trouble. 
I have tried to dl the latest .traineddata from github but it doesnt change anyhing. 
I have uninstalled and re-installed the soft too.
Using tesseract --list-langs i am able to see deu, fra, spa and ita.

I have been reading the source code from Github, that makes this error message pop. But I cant find what I am doing wrong.
As I said it works just fine with any languages, except those 4.

Hopefully you will have a lead on this one

Answer (score 10):

I got this problem too.
In my case it is because of using the wrong version of trained data file.
I have use https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata (master).

This is for tesseract 4 (for this date 15/1/2017). 
The solution is use this https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/tree/3.04.00.

hope this helps.